# Map function doesn't work in for loop

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm trying to merge two lists if they contain a certain word.

My code works fine until I try to transfer it to under a function or under a for loop.
When I do I get:

```
TypeError: argument 2 to map() must support iteration
```

I also tried replacing `map(None, a,b)` with `itertools.imap(None, a,b)` as suggested in other posts but get :

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Any suggestions?

```
a = 0
b = 0
row_combine = []
for row in blank3:

    if 'GOVERNMENTAL' in row:
        a = row
    if 'ACTIVITIES' in row:
        b = row
c = map(None, a,b) #problem is here
for row in c:
    row1 = []
    if row[0] == None:
        row1.append(''.join([''] + [row[1]]))
    else:
        row1.append(''.join([row[0]] + [' '] + [row[1]]))
    row_combine.append(''.join(row1))
```

output for `a`:

```
a = [' ', u'GOVERNMENTAL', u'BUSINESS-TYPE']
```

output for `b`:

```
b = [u'ASSETS', u'ACTIVITIES', u'ACTIVITIES', u'2009', u'2008', u'JEDO']
```

need it to be:

```
[ u'ASSETS', u'GOVERNMENTAL ACTIVITIES', u'BUSINESS-TYPE ACTIVITIES', u'2009', u'2008', u'JEDO']
```

hence the for for loop after map function.

Comment: Can't tell what you're trying to do here, but whatever it is, I'm fairly certain map isn't the way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If after iterating through `blank3` you never encounter both 'GOVERNMENTAL' and 'ACTIVITIES', `a` or `b` could be 0, which will cause map to fail.  You could start `a` and `b` off as empty lists, or check your input before the `map()`

Meanwhile, instead of the for loop:

```
row_combine = map(lambda x, y: ((x or '') + ' ' + (y or '')).strip(), a, b)
```

Which yields:

```
[u'ASSETS', u'GOVERNMENTAL ACTIVITIES', u'BUSINESS-TYPE ACTIVITIES', u'2009', u'2008', u'JEDO']
```